# Chart.js click on labels, using bar chart

Tags: charts, chart.js

i need help with my Chart.js interactivity. When I click on the label, I need to return the column(index) number at which I clicked.

I tried to use getElementsAtEvent but it only work if I click directly at chart.

This http://jsfiddle.net/yxz2sjam/ is pretty much what I am looking for but getPointsAtEvent is no longer available in the new versions.

```
canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
var points = chart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
alert(chart.datasets[0].points.indexOf(points[0]));
};
```

I also found this http://jsfiddle.net/1Lngmtz7/ but it isn't working with bar chart.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: data
    })

    $('#myChart').click(function (e) {
        var helpers = Chart.helpers;

        var eventPosition = helpers.getRelativePosition(e, myRadarChart.chart);
        var mouseX = eventPosition.x;
        var mouseY = eventPosition.y;

        var activePoints = [];
        helpers.each(myRadarChart.scale.ticks, function (label, index) {
            for (var i = this.getValueCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var pointLabelPosition = this.getPointPosition(i, this.getDistanceFromCenterForValue(this.options.reverse ? this.min : this.max) + 5);

                var pointLabelFontSize = helpers.getValueOrDefault(this.options.pointLabels.fontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize);
                var pointLabeFontStyle = helpers.getValueOrDefault(this.options.pointLabels.fontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle);
                var pointLabeFontFamily = helpers.getValueOrDefault(this.options.pointLabels.fontFamily, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                var pointLabeFont = helpers.fontString(pointLabelFontSize, pointLabeFontStyle, pointLabeFontFamily);
                ctx.font = pointLabeFont;

                var labelsCount = this.pointLabels.length,
                    halfLabelsCount = this.pointLabels.length / 2,
                    quarterLabelsCount = halfLabelsCount / 2,
                    upperHalf = (i < quarterLabelsCount || i > labelsCount - quarterLabelsCount),
                    exactQuarter = (i === quarterLabelsCount || i === labelsCount - quarterLabelsCount);
                var width = ctx.measureText(this.pointLabels[i]).width;
                var height = pointLabelFontSize;

                var x, y;

                if (i === 0 || i === halfLabelsCount)
                    x = pointLabelPosition.x - width / 2;
                else if (i < halfLabelsCount)
                    x = pointLabelPosition.x;
                else
                    x = pointLabelPosition.x - width;

                if (exactQuarter)
                    y = pointLabelPosition.y - height / 2;
                else if (upperHalf)
                    y = pointLabelPosition.y - height;
                else
                    y = pointLabelPosition.y

                if ((mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + height) && (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + width))
                    activePoints.push({ index: i, label: this.pointLabels[i] });
            }
        }, myRadarChart.scale);

        var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
        if (firstPoint !== undefined) {
            alert(firstPoint.index + ': ' + firstPoint.label);
        }
    });
```

Thank for response.

Comment: reading this and interacting with the graph helped me get what I wanted working http://plnkr.co/edit/GsOi2hX42389VJnuzGhv?p=preview which came from this thread https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2802 if you need more to look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem with

```
document.getElementById("chart").onclick = function(e) 
{
    var activeElement = weatherMainChart.lastTooltipActive;
    console.log(activeElement[0]._index);
};
```

this solution register clicks on chart and label, then I restricted it with e.layerY to register only clicks on label section.

```
document.getElementById("chart").onclick = function(e) 
{
    var activeElement = weatherMainChart.lastTooltipActive;
    if(e.layerY > 843 && e.layerY < 866 && activeElement[0] !== undefined)
        console.log(activeElement[0]._index);
};
```

Comment: `843` and `866` are values of what, exactly? I'm guessing it's the upper and lower (Y) bounds of the bart chart labels? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes they are exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a click handler through the onClick option you can use the following code using the getElementsAtEventForMode() call:

```
function handleClick(evt) {
    var col;
    switch(chartType) {
        case "horizontalBar":
            this.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, "y", 1).forEach(function(item) { col = item._index });
            break;

        case "bar":
            this.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, "x", 1).forEach(function(item) { col = item._index });
            break;
    }

    if (!col) {
        return;
    }

    alert("Column " + col + " was selected");
};
```

You'll probably need to add extra switch checks for other chart types but I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using version 2.4.0, i created an onClick Event, and inside it

```js
var activeIndex = localChart.tooltip._lastActive[0]._index;
var clickCoordinates = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, localChart.chart);
if (clickCoordinates.y >= 530) { //custom value, depends on chart style,size, etc
    alert("clicked on " + localChart.data.labels[activeIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what's the `530` value exactly?

Comment: Some time has passed so please accept a bit of vagueness. 
As the similar solution from Nivelety the closest way to detect the label value was passin through click coordinates, relative to the chart size.
In my case i had tooltip activated, so i used the _lastactive value to get that column index.
Then i picked the click coordinates, and if the y was higher than 530 (alas in the lower part of the chart with fixed dimensions) i went to pick the label at the correct index.
As i wrote in comment it depends on chart style, size, etc; if size is variable... i fear it's harder.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
I Solved this problem with single or multiple label click you will be find using true/false

First you need to set your chartJs Id click 

below code SessionChart = Your ChartJs ID e.g. ("myChart") I was replace it for my Id

document.getElementById("SessionChart").onclick = function (evt) {
var meta = SubscriberSessionChart.getDatasetMeta(0);
  if (meta.$filler.chart.legend.legendItems[0].text.toLowerCase() "sessions") 
  {
      if (meta.$filler.chart.legend.legendItems[0].hidden) {
             sessionHidden = true;
      }
   }
}

here "sessions" = first label text

meta.$filler.chart.legend.legendItems[0].text.toLowerCase() = is your first label 
from Array so you can get multiple label's click here true / false

if (meta.$filler.chart.legend.legendItems[0].hidden) = your label is not active then 
you will get hidden true otherwise you will get false if not tick on label 
by default label tick hidden is false in chart js
```