# Clickable labels in Radar chart - Charjs with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, radar-chart

I want to make my radar chart labels clickable. I am using Vue2 with chartjs 2.9.4. Can you please tell me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: This question was still asked.. does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470784/make-chart-js-radar-labels-clickable

Comment: @Bobby - I already tried. The issue is I cannot access helpers with chartjs version 2.9.4. When I upgrade it, it doesn't support with Vue 2. If you know some alternative way, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I was able to resolve it with the help of [Chart.js turn labels into links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973533/chart-js-turn-labels-into-links). I was using Primevue chartjs and it didn't support for chartjs latest versions. Hence I got rid of it and followed the answer from above mentioned link.